# Template literal throws errors in some scenarios but not others

Tags: javascript, typescript

As part of a code review a colleague recommended using a type rather than an enum. Whilst making the changes we found an issue neither of us expected.

We'd expect scenario one and two to throw compiler and/or intellisense errors as one of the values does not exist on the type. However, after testing we found only scenario one throws errors whilst scenario two resolves without issue.

This is likely an understanding issue but from everything I've read (e.g. [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) we should be getting errors when a provided value doesn't exist.

Based on the above, is anyone able to explain why we only see errors on scenario one but not the scenario two?

### Scenario One

**Example Code**

```js
export type FileType = ".png" | ".tif" | ".tiff" | ".jpeg" | ".jpg";

const allowedFileTypes = [".exe"] as Array<FileType>;
```

**Expectation:** Compiler error as `.exe` doesn't exist

**Outcome:** Compiler error stating the value doesn't exist

### Scenario Two

**Example Code**

```js
export type FileType = ".png" | ".tif" | ".tiff" | ".jpeg" | ".jpg";

const allowedFileTypes = [".exe", ".jpeg"] as Array<FileType>;
```

**Expectation:** Compiler error as `.exe` doesn't exist

**Outcome:** No compiler errors

### Scenario Three

**Example Code**

```js
export type FileType = ".png" | ".tif" | ".tiff" | ".jpeg" | ".jpg";

const allowedFileTypes = [".png", ".jpeg"] as Array<FileType>;
```

**Expectation:** No compiler errors

**Outcome:** No compiler errors

Comment: Like pointed out, your overriding the type.  But just a heads up, you can also do `[]` syntax for arrays, I think it just looks nicer.. eg..  `const allowedFileTypes: FileType[] = [".exe", ".jpeg"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as Type` is a way of saying "This value **is** this type, even if it doesn't look like it".

You're overriding normal type detection.

It's useful for things like:

```
const response = await fetch('/some/url');
const data = await response.json();
return data as Foo;
```

where you *know* what the shape of the data you are getting back from the HTTP request is, but the compiler has no way of telling that unless you use `as` to tell it explicitly.

---

It is dangerous since you can specify a type that *doesn't* match the value you actually have (as you've discovered).

I have a project underway where I'm using superstruct in order to test the shape of my data inside a typeguard function instead of trusting to `as`.

---

You need to specify what is allowed to be assigned to the variable instead:

```
const allowedFileTypes: Array<FileType> = [".exe", ".jpeg"];
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Reading over your answer makes perfect sense now and I don't know why I didn't think of it before.